# symfony2 sessions, cookies, or something completely different?

Tags: session, cookies, symfony

I am currently making a time-clock system that is inside of a custom-built application (CRM) that a previous developer did.  I've got the timeclock coming along nicely but have just a few questions..

Upon clocking in I set a session like so: `$this->get('session')->set('clockedin', 'true');`

I set a session so that I in order to show the clockin or clockout button I figured the easiest method would be to just read a session variable to determine which button to show using a twig if/else statement in the templates (i have the buttons show in 2 places, 1 is in every page and 1 is only in the timeclock system itself)

So, is this the best way to go about doing this or is there a better recommended way of going about it?

The next thing I wondered about is session expiration...  in my config.yml I see:

```
session:
    cookie_lifetime:       43200
    auto_start:     true
```

So, does this mean that the way i've set it lasts for 12 hours?  Or in order for that to be true, would I need to use a cookie instead?  I think that a cookie might be better, because if the browser closes (many of the employees aren't technologically inclined) I'd need this to be a persistent upon the next page load..

Thanks for any help..

Comment: cookie_lifetime resides under framework.session?? If I set it there, I get this error: Unrecognized options "cookie_lifetime" under "framework.session. Doesn't it come out that for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If another indefinitely later operation depends on `clockedin` state I would not rely on sessions. If user logs him/herself out session gets invalidated (whole session), so `clockedin` would be lost.

I would rather use `{% include %}` or `{% render %}` to determine state every time you need to display that button. For example:

```
/**
 * @Template()
 */
public function clockedInAction(){
   .... // do some login here
   $clocked_in = ....;
   return array(
        'clockedin' => $clockedin
   );
}
```

and in your Twig:

```
{% render "AcmeBundle:SomeController:clockedIn" %}
```

Template of this controller would contains that `{% if .... %}` you wanted originally:

```
{# AcmeBundle:SomeController:clockedIn.html.twig #}
{% if clockedIn %}
   display "Clocked In" button
{% else %}
   display "Clocked Out" button
{% endif %}
```

Now, this is more expensive since on each request you have to assess the situation and then print appropriate template, but it's always consistent with a system...